# Using having clause twice in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, having

I have two queries

```
select a,b,c,count(d) as first_count from
test
group by a,b,c
having (count(c)>1)
```

and second one

```
    select a,b,c,count(d) as second_count  from
    test
    group by a,b,c
    having (count(c)>100)
```

How can i do the above operation in one query such that in my result i have following  columns : `a,b,c,count(d) as first_count,count(d) as second_count`

Comment: Please show small sample of desired results.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you

```
 select a,b,c,(select count(d)  from test having (count(c)>1) )   as first_count,
              (select count(d)  from test having (count(c)>100) ) as second_count
 FROM test
 group by a,b,c
```

Comment: You don't need the group by if you are using scalar sub-queries in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` if you want to merge both query results

```
(select a,b,c,count(d) as first_count ,0 as second_count
from test
group by a,b,c
having first_count>1)
UNION
(select a,b,c,0 as first_count,count(d) as second_count  
from test
group by a,b,c
having second_count>100)
```

or with in a single query you can filter using both count results based on your criteria using `AND` operation or `OR` operation

```
select a,b,c,count(d) as first_count from,count(d) as second_count
FROM test
group by a,b,c
having first_count>1 AND second_count >100
```

Comment: `FROM` goes before the table name.

Comment: it gives me same values in both counts

Comment: @Developer add your sample data amd desired result set that you need from the query

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
SELECT a, b, c, 
       SUM(count >   1) first_count,
       SUM(count > 100) second_count 
  FROM 
(
  SELECT a, b, c, COUNT(*) count
    FROM test
   GROUP BY a, b, c
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q
 GROUP BY a, b, c
```

Comment: @Developer Did it help in any way?